# File Structure of AUTOSAR BSW Modules

Tags: c, embedded, autosar, automotive

I noticed in the last versions of AUTOSAR that the standard does not provide the file structure to follow for BSW modules.

Before, the *.c, *.h files and the different interactions between them were clearly defined, here is an example from the CAN Driver:

**- Version 4.3.1**

[image]

**- Version R23-11**
[image]

Does anyone have an idea on why is that?

Comment: I was also wondering, but in the end, all BSW modules shall follow the definitions in AUTOSAR_SWS_BSWGeneral. It is common sense, to only include in the <BSW>.h the headers needed to define the BSWs interface, and include the rest in the .c implementation files. There are some specific implementation files mentioned in BSWGeneral, like <BSW>_Irq.c or <BSW>_PBCfg.c or <BSW>_LCfg.c, but in the end, its the implementers responsibility to define their file structure. External dependencies are listed now also in the ch. 8 "API" section (Imported Types and External/Optional interfaces.

Comment: What is the purpose of this information?  How is it useful?  The term "file structure" here is confusing - that is not a normal meaning if the term.  That diagram shows the file inclusion structure.  Such diagrams can be generated by reverse engineering tools such as Doxygen.

Comment: @kesselhaus, how I understand this change (but I don't have the confirmation) is that the standard used to define a specific structure for each module but now it's not part of the standard anymore and it's part of the "Compete on Implementation", do you agree ?

Comment: @Clifford, it's true that the term is somehow is confusing but it's just how AUTOSAR decided to name it, and you're right it only shows the inclusions paths. One can have different file structures for the same "Inclusion" structure.
For the Doxygen part, this assumes you have already some AUTOSAR compliant code. But the question here is should one (who wants to start from scratch for example) respect a specific File structure to be able to claim compliancy with these new AUTOSAR versions ?

Comment: I am not familiar with AUTOSAR (and nothing I know about it enhances my ill-informed opinion), but I would assume that that diagram is _documentation_ not _specification_.  A header provides an interface, and ultimately it is the interfaces that are declared by it's inclusion that are important, not the nested headers that each provide or support those interfaces.  Why should you care?  I imagine the omission of this _documentation_ is because it serves no purpose. Moreover to unnecessarily document these internal _implementation details_ just makes the documentation quickly out of date.

Comment: @Clifford, it is specification. Why? Because it defines a certain layout of your implementation across vendors, what it shall contain, and how it should depend on. e.g. `Can_Irq.c` would only implement the ISRs, nothing else. `Can_LCfg.c/.h` shall be generated by the config tool with LINKTIME config items, `Can_PBCfg.c/.h` shall contain POSTBUILD config items (which can be exchanged without changing the static code. `Can_Cfg.h` contain PRECOMPILE config elements to e.g. dis/enable features. `Can.h` is *the* Can drivers component interface. I could change from vendor A to B with same deps.

Comment: I agree that what should be defined by can.c can_irq.c may need specification, but other than the primary header declaring the application API, everything else is an implementation detail.  Why for example should can.c include spi.h? For an MCU with an on chip CAN controller, I cannot imagine why that is relevant.

Comment: In any case unless someone from the AUTOSAR standard setting body cares to engage, the question is off-topic as it is clearly going to be opinion based.  My comments are nothing but opinion.

Comment: I could try to ask in our monthly AUTOSAR TechBoards I'm attending. Not sure, if I'll get an answer though.

Comment: @kesselhaus, what are these TechBoards, may I ask ?

Comment: @E_genin, the company I work for is one of the AUTOSAR Consortium Core members, and these TechBoards are, were we discuss our internal AR CP & AP Stack features, status of new features. But we also check out and work on new concepts on autosar.org either raised by us or other members of AUTOSAR. e.g. we have been part of the ISO23150 and the AR ADI_SensorInterfaces (not me personally). Lately I also raised issues about useless AR model changes with impact on tooling compatability. Or Dem/FiM issues in Safetycritical envs, and why all vendors or division draw their own safe Dem replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some info out of our TechBoard Architecture&BSW.

The file structure chapter does not contain the file layout structure anymore, because even in the past, it was incomplete, missing certain information and would have made the diagram less readable.

The information, what the BSW module defines or imports is now part of the chapter 8 API specification:

- the imported types include a table with

  - module from where to import
  - the header where the type can be found
  - the imported type itself

[image: CanIf Imported Types table]

- the types a module defines and also the functions contain in its specification table the element "available via"

[image: CanIf defined types]

[image: CanIf functions]

- the mandatory and optional interfaces again have each a table with the function itself and the header by which it as available

[image: CanIf mandatory files]

As you can see, the exclusive areas are provided by the SchM_CanIf.h generated by the Configuration tool. If CanIf would have a CanIf_MainFunction, this would also come from the `SchM_CanIf.h` now.

[image: CanIf Optional Interfaces]

As you can see, CanIf would include `CanTp.h` to access actually `CanTp_RxIndication` from CanTp, but for CanSM, to access `CanSM_ControllerBusOff`, there is a separate interface header `CanSM_CanIf.h`. CanSm itself specifies this again over the API description of `CanSM_CanControllerBusOff` in the "availabel via CanSM_CanIF.h".

[image: CanSM CanSM_CanControllerBusOff sepcification]

The remaining information can be taken from the AUTOSAR_SWS_BSWGeneral, which is the base of all BSW module specification.

Especially chapter 5 is here the source of information:

Implementation sources could be mandatory (e.g. the static code of a BSW module) or optional (e.g. depending on configuration generation).

There is also a specific naming like `<Mip>_Cfg` vs `<Mip>_LCfg` vs `<Mip>_PBCfg` vs `<Mip>_Irq`.

[image: BSW Implementation source table]

You have the freedom for design of configurations to include `<Mip>_Cfg.c` and `<Mip>_LCfg.c` parameters into the `<Mip>_PBCfg.c` configuration file in case you use PostBuild configuration, and mix them in maybe a single data structure of the PostBuild config. Then you would not need the `<Mip>_Cfg.c` and `<Mip>_LCfg.c` files.

There is no table for the headers, but there are also some rules.

- `<Mip>_Cfg.h` for Precompile config, e.g. enable/disable features

  - like `#define CAN_DEVERRORDETECT  STD_ON`
  - or `#define CANTRCV_WAKEUP_SUPPORT STD_ON` to enable certain code parts/functions/variables, but some other parameters are maybe configured by a PostBuild configuration e.g. `<Mip>_PBCfg.c` contains

    - PbCfg_A: `.CanPncFrameId = 0x500`
    - PbCfg_B: `.CanPncFrameId = 0x501`
- `<Mip>_LCfg.h` for Linktime config
- `<Mip>_PBCfg.h` for PostBuild config
- `Rte_<Mip>_Types.h` for types used in RTE in order to not declare them twice (Impl header vs Rte Header). This should be included by Module Implementation header. The types are actually generated in `Rte_Type.h` which the `Rte_<Mip>_Types.h` includes

  - e.g. NvM.h -include-> Rte_NvM_Types.h -include-> Rte_Types.h
- `Rte_<Mip>.h` - Rte Interfaces of BSW/SWC, should not be included by Implementation header file, but actually source file

  - NvM.h should NOT include Rte_NvM.h
  - NvM.c should include Rte_NvM.h
- `SchM_<Mip>.h` - declaration of MainFunctions and ExclusiveAreas, shall also be included by source files and not through other headers

So, in the end, you have more freedom, better definitions of where things are defined, and by the other rules in AUTOSAR_SWS_BSWGeneral also some guidelines, what to define where, and where you should not define it. But you have to read a bit more to gather the info.

I guess, the post is long enough to stop here. :D